# Getting column data using SQLx with Rust

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx, rust-axum

I am using Axum and sqlx to build an api endpoint that takes a table name and returns all the data in the table in the form of json. The number of columns and their types are not known beforehand. What would be the best way to go about this.

I did write the following code:

```
 let query = format!("SELECT * FROM {}", table);
 let result = sqlx::query(&query).fetch_all(&db).await.unwrap();
 for row in result.iter() {
   for col in row.columns() {
       let value = row.try_get(col.name()).unwrap();
    }
 }
```

Of course value needs a type, I tried using an enum and a Vector of that enum to store the values but couldnt get it right. Any nudging towards the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with the same issue in the past few days. I am a newbie to Rust.

I don't have a solution yet, but I have made tiny "progress" toward the solution -- I believe.

Please let me present what I have done so far.

The database I used is [Oracle Corporation MySQL test data](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db).

I am using the below stored procedure for investigating this issue:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `DemoStoredProc1`( pm_dept_no varchar(4) )
    READS SQL DATA
begin
  select * from departments where dept_no = pm_dept_no;
  select * from dept_manager where dept_no = pm_dept_no;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The structure of the table `departments`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  `dept_no` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `dept_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dept_no`),
  UNIQUE KEY `dept_name` (`dept_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The structure of the table `dept_manager`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `dept_manager` (
  `emp_no` int NOT NULL,
  `dept_no` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `from_date` date NOT NULL,
  `to_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`,`dept_no`),
  KEY `dept_no` (`dept_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `dept_manager_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_no`) REFERENCES `employees` (`emp_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `dept_manager_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_no`) REFERENCES `departments` (`dept_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is my test method:

```rust
async fn do_run_stored_proc(pool: &sqlx::Pool<MySql>, dept_no: &str) {
    let result = sqlx::query("call DemoStoredProc1(?)")
    .bind(dept_no)
    .fetch_all(pool).await;

    match result {
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error select data for department number: {}", dept_no);
            println!("Error message: [{}].\n", e.to_string());
        }

        Ok(query_result) => {
            for (rindex, row) in query_result.iter().enumerate() {
                println!("\n* Row number: {}", rindex+1);

                println!("* Total columns: {}\n", row.columns().len());

                for (cindex, col) in row.columns().iter().enumerate() {
                    println!(">> {}.", cindex+1);

                    println!(">> {:#?}", col.type_info());
                    println!(">> Name: {}. Type Name: {}.", col.name(), col.type_info().name());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints out the following output:

```
* Row number: 1
* Total columns: 2

>> 1.
>> MySqlTypeInfo {
    type: String,
    flags: ColumnFlags(
        NOT_NULL | PRIMARY_KEY | NO_DEFAULT_VALUE,
    ),
    char_set: 224,
    max_size: Some(
        16,
    ),
}
>> Name: dept_no. Type Name: CHAR.
>> 2.
>> MySqlTypeInfo {
    type: VarString,
    flags: ColumnFlags(
        NOT_NULL | UNIQUE_KEY | NO_DEFAULT_VALUE,
    ),
    char_set: 224,
    max_size: Some(
        160,
    ),
}
>> Name: dept_name. Type Name: VARCHAR.

* Row number: 2
* Total columns: 4

>> 1.
>> MySqlTypeInfo {
    type: Long,
    flags: ColumnFlags(
        NOT_NULL | PRIMARY_KEY | NO_DEFAULT_VALUE,
    ),
    char_set: 63,
    max_size: Some(
        11,
    ),
}
>> Name: emp_no. Type Name: INT.
>> 2.
>> MySqlTypeInfo {
    type: String,
    flags: ColumnFlags(
        NOT_NULL | PRIMARY_KEY | MULTIPLE_KEY | NO_DEFAULT_VALUE,
    ),
    char_set: 224,
    max_size: Some(
        16,
    ),
}
>> Name: dept_no. Type Name: CHAR.
>> 3.
>> MySqlTypeInfo {
    type: Date,
    flags: ColumnFlags(
        NOT_NULL | BINARY | NO_DEFAULT_VALUE,
    ),
    char_set: 63,
    max_size: Some(
        10,
    ),
}
>> Name: from_date. Type Name: DATE.
>> 4.
>> MySqlTypeInfo {
    type: Date,
    flags: ColumnFlags(
        NOT_NULL | BINARY | NO_DEFAULT_VALUE,
    ),
    char_set: 63,
    max_size: Some(
        10,
    ),
}
>> Name: to_date. Type Name: DATE.

* Row number: 3
* Total columns: 4
...
```

I am able to extract the column type names. Such as:

```
>> Name: dept_no. Type Name: CHAR.
...
>> Name: to_date. Type Name: DATE.
```

I do understand that this not what you are looking for, neither I am.

But this is still a tiny progress for me, I thought would just share it.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic casting you want does require an enum. Using serde_json, I managed to get it to work:

```
 use serde_json::json;
 use sqlx::{Column, Row, TypeInfo};
 use std::collections::HashMap;

 . . . .

 let query = format!("SELECT * FROM {}", table);
 let result: Vec<_> = sqlx::query(&query).fetch_all(&db).await.unwrap()
   .into_iter()
   .map(|row| {
     json!(row
       .columns()
       .into_iter()
       .map(|column| {
         let ordinal = column.ordinal();
         let type_name = column.type_info().name();
         (
           column.name(),
           match type_name {
             "TEXT" => json!(row.get::<String, _>(ordinal)),
             "INTEGER" => json!(row.get::<i64, _>(ordinal)),
             "BOOLEAN" => json!(row.get::<bool, _>(ordinal)),
             "REAL" => json!(row.get::<f64, _>(ordinal)),
             // probably missed a few other types?
             _ => {
               json!(format!("UNPROCESSED TYPE '{}'", type_name))
             }
           },
         )
       })
       .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>())
   })
   .collect();
 println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&result).unwrap());
```